# TensorFlow: ImportError: cannot import name 'dragon4_positional'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I get the following error when trying to use tensorflow

> importError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py in ()
>        22 
>        23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
>   ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
>        25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
>        26
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py in
>   ()
>        54 # imported using `tf.load_op_library()` can access symbols defined in
>        55 # _pywrap_tensorflow.so.
>   ---> 56 import numpy as np
>        57 try:
>        58   if hasattr(sys, 'getdlopenflags') and hasattr(sys, 'setdlopenflags'):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py in ()
>       140         return loader(*packages, **options)
>       141 
>   --> 142     from . import add_newdocs
>       143     **all** = ['add_newdocs',
>       144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in ()
>        11 from **future** import division, absolute_import, print_function
>        12 
>   ---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
>        14 
>        15 ###############################################################################
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib__init__.py in ()
>         6 from numpy.version import version as **version**
>         7 
>   ----> 8 from .type_check import *
>         9 from .index_tricks import *
>        10 from .function_base import *
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py in ()
>         9            'common_type']
>        10 
>   ---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
>        12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, zeros
>        13 from .ufunclike import isneginf, isposinf
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py in ()
>        36 from . import numerictypes as nt
>        37 multiarray.set_typeDict(nt.sctypeDict)
>   ---> 38 from . import numeric
>        39 from .numeric import *
>        40 from . import fromnumeric
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in ()
>   1818     1819 # Use numarray's printing function
>   -> 1820 from .arrayprint import array2string, get_printoptions, set_printoptions    1821     1822
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py in ()
>        42 from .umath import absolute, not_equal, isnan, isinf, isfinite, isnat
>        43 from . import multiarray
>   ---> 44 from .multiarray import (array, dragon4_positional, dragon4_scientific,
>        45                          datetime_as_string, datetime_data, dtype, ndarray,
>        46                          set_legacy_print_mode)

This error occured after I tried to upgrade TF from version 1.1 to the latest version. So I dont know what current TF version I am using.
I am using Windows 10 without a GPU.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What are your imports? What version of Tensorflow are you using? What OS? GPU or non-GPU?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is an issue with Numpy, which is a dependency of Tensorflow. Did you try upgrading your version of numpy using pip or conda?

Like such: `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade numpy`

Answer (score -1):

your numpy has been corrupted. probably pip install and conda install wont work here to install numpy again. try if it helps, otherwise use follow these:

download zip file of numpy from https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files
extract the numpy folder from the zip file
copy and paste the numpy folder at:   C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/